# Error binding to target method

Tags: c#, reflection, binding, dynamic

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
parse = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T,string>), method);
```

T is a float in this case. However I am getting a Error binding to target method. Parse I believe is a static method. I have looked at other examples, but I can not figure out why it is not binding.

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just had the delegate method backward                                                              MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
parse = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string,T>), method);

Comment: That's just repeating what's in the question. A short but *complete* program would have been something we could compile and run *with no further changes*. Not just part of a generic type/method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to swap `T` and `string` because the method returns a `T` not a `string`.

I replaced `T` with `float` and following code works for me:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(float).GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);

var parse = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, float>), method);
```

source: VS intellisense and MSDN [Func(Of T, TResult) Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Comment: Wow that was a very simple. Thanks. I was just racking my head, but didn't look for a such a small thing.